# MongoDB "atomic" find entity and if not found update a different one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, concurrency, race-condition

I am trying to solve a race condition issue through MongoDB operations so I can avoid the implementation of locks.

My goal is to be able to check if there is any document with a certain status in the collection and if not, to set that status to an existing document of the collection of my choice. That goal comes from the need that due to concurrency any implementation I tried makes that with a race condition I get more than one document updated.

Let me put a parallel example. In a scenario of concurrent calls, my goal is that the logic checks if there is not any existing Card that has status ACTIVE, a Card of my choice is set to ACTIVE, and if there is already an ACTIVE Card, to leave that as it is. All in just one MongoDB operation. This operation is triggered by a different flow so I can't change the flow to set as ACTIVE a Card before executing that logic.

I tried through the use of the `findOneAndUpdate` (and even `findOneAndReplace`) operation:

```
const query = {
  userId: 'user-id-1',
  status: 'ACTIVE',
};

Card.findOneAndUpdate(
    query,
    {
        $set: {
            _id: 'chosen-id', // A certain chosen ID to update if not found.
            userId: 'user-id-1', 
            status: 'ACTIVE',
        },
    },
    {
        upsert: true,
        returnNewDocument: true,
    }
);
```

But I find myself unable to achieve my goal with any of the options available, therefore I only achieve to update a found Card. If not found, anything remains the same and my chosen Card is not set as ACTIVE. The only case is when adding like in the example `upsert: true` I can create a new document, but I do not want as I want to update a different existing document.

An example case of documents:

```
{ "_id": "card-id-1", "userId": "user-id-1", "status": "READY" }
{ "_id": "card-id-2", "userId": "user-id-1", "status": "CANCELLED" }
{ "_id": "card-id-3", "userId": "user-id-1", "status": "READY" }
{ "_id": "card-id-4", "userId": "user-id-1", "status": "READY" }
```

For this case, when executing and choosing `card-id-4` as the fallback one if no ACTIVE found, the expected result should be:

```
{ "_id": "card-id-1", "userId": "user-id-1", "status": "READY" }
{ "_id": "card-id-2", "userId": "user-id-1", "status": "CANCELLED" }
{ "_id": "card-id-3", "userId": "user-id-1", "status": "READY" }
{ "_id": "card-id-4", "userId": "user-id-1", "status": "ACTIVE" }
```

If executed again, the collection should remain the same, as `card-id-4` is ACTIVE so the operation is finding one.

Has MongoDB any implementation that can achieve this behaviour in one single operation? Regardless of the version. I have no limitations in upgrading if needed.

Comment: @ray done. Hopefully is enough to give more context.

Comment: Have you looked at multi-document transactions in MongoDB?

Comment: @Joe my first attempt was with MongoDB transactions but I couldn't make it work. Not sure if using Mongoose as ORM was at fault on that matter. Thus why I was curious if there would be a MongoDB operation alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$facet` to check for the existence of an ACTIVE record
2. depends on the result:

   - set `_id` to active record's `_id` if found
   - set `_id` to fallback `_id` if not found
3. `$merge` the constructed update object back to the collection using `_id`

Operations on a single document level are atomic by default. So, you don't need to worry much about race condition.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "hasActive": [
        {
          $match: {
            userId: "user-id-1",
            status: "ACTIVE"
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $first: "$hasActive._id"
          },
          "card-id-4"// chosen fallback id
          
        ]
      },
      userId: "user-id-1",
      status: "ACTIVE"
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground when no active](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QBjU-18FgVD)

[Mongo Playground when there is active](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3GFle3dv39-)

Comment: Operations on a single document may be atomic, but aggregation pipelines are not, if that pipeilne were to be run by 2 clients at the same time, there would still be a race.

Comment: This worked as quick implementation even though the aggregate pipeline is not returning the modified result. Any hint why might happening? I can't find an option in the $merge stage to force to provide the modified document in the output.
I still have to test concurrency issues in different scenarios, so I will still need to check what @Joe mentions.